# Extract Month from DateTime field in sql

Tags: sql-server

How can I extract Month from DateTime field in sql server.

**dXFactory = 2021-04-22 13:12:26.000**

I need it like this.

**Months = April**

How can I do this in sql server?

Comment: [DATENAME (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DATENAME function, like this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dXFactory)
```

assuming dXFactory is a date field

Comment: `SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, dXFactory) , year(dXFactory)` I used these in two times. Can't I use this at once and get result in one column?

Comment: Yes, in that case you can use FORMAT function, like this: SELECT FORMAT(dxFactory, 'MMMM yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATENAME`

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,'2021-04-22 13:12:26.000') [Month Name]
```

or for your column name

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, dXFactory) [Month Name]
```

Check on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70babdab84a9ecacf6986e89cddaba15)

Comment: Using string literals for aliases is generally not recommended. It is confusing (especially for new users), and it is the only place the behaviour works. A clause like `WHERE 'Month Name' = 'April'` or `ORDER BY 'Month Name'` would *not* reference the column aliased as `'Month Name'` in the dataset.